# Can we Convert KStream to Global KTable in Apache Kafka?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I am trying to work in scala for kafka streams. I am wondering if it's possible to convert a `KStream` to a `GlobalKTable`?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow! I find it hard to understand your question. Can you explain more on what you mean with "kafka streams" and "convert"? My understanding is that Kafka Streams is a library and I doubt that this can be converted into a KTable. It would be best to include some code to describe your question.

Comment: Well. I mean Just like we can apply aggregate function on KStream and it makes the result in Ktable, can we somehow make it a Global Ktable instead of a ktable?

I haven't started code yet, I am a beginner. trying to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert a kstream directly to globalKtable, but u can create one directly; refer  [kstreams](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html) for more detailed basics understanding.

For creating a globalKtable ;

```
val builder = new StreamsBuilder()
val globalMaterialized: Materialized[String, String, KeyValueStore[Bytes, Array[Byte]]] =
      Materialized.as("global_store_name").withKeySerde(Serdes.String).withValueSerde(Serdes.String)
builder.globalTable("topic_name", globalMaterialized)
```

Attach the GlobalKtable to processor for accessing it.

Comment: I the the point is, that one would need to write the `KStream` into a topic and use the `KStream` output topic as input topic for the `GlobalKTable`.